# MariaDB: Using composite primary key and index on the same columns gives strange results

Tags: index, mariadb, primary-key

Environment information:
Windows 11
10.6.8-MariaDB

In SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055644/mysql-counter-within-group
I asked how can I add a counter within a group. It works quite well until I found a conflict when primary key and index are defined on the same columns.

Here is the example with real data:

```
SELECT *
FROM table0
ORDER BY id, date


+--------+------------+
|   id   |   date     |
+--------+------------+
| 120792 | 2010-03-22 |
| 120792 | 2010-10-23 |
| 120792 | 2010-11-12 |
...
+--------+------------+
```

Here are the size informations:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), COUNT(DISTINCT id), COUNT(DISTINCT date)
FROM table0
;

+----------+--------------------+-----------------------+
| COUNT(*) | COUNT(DISTINCT id) | COUNT(DISTINCT date)  |
+----------+--------------------+-----------------------+
|    50835 |               4394 |                  3666 |
+----------+--------------------+-----------------------+
```

... and here are three variations of index I tested:

```
-- Case (1): 
ALTER TABLE table0 ADD PRIMARY KEY(id,date);
+-----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+
|  Table    | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Ignored |
+-----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+
| table0    |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id          | A         |       10208 | \N       | \N     |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
| table0    |          0 | PRIMARY  |            2 | date        | A         |       51040 | \N       | \N     |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
+-----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+

-- Case (2):
ALTER TABLE table0 ADD INDEX(id);
ALTER TABLE table0 ADD INDEX(date);
+-----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+
|  Table    | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Ignored |
+-----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+
| table0    |          1 | id       |            1 | id          | A         |       10200 | \N       | \N     |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
| table0    |          1 | date     |            1 | date        | A         |        7285 | \N       | \N     |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
+-----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+

-- Case (3):
ALTER TABLE table0 ADD PRIMARY KEY(id,date);
ALTER TABLE table0 ADD INDEX(id);
ALTER TABLE table0 ADD INDEX(date);
+-----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+
|  Table    | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Ignored |
+-----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+
| table0    |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id          | A         |       10208 | \N       | \N     |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
| table0    |          0 | PRIMARY  |            2 | date        | A         |       51040 | \N       | \N     |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
| table0    |          1 | id       |            1 | id          | A         |       10208 | \N       | \N     |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
| table0    |          1 | date     |            1 | date        | A         |        8506 | \N       | \N     |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
+-----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+
```

The query to add a counter within grouping column `id` is:

```
SELECT id
     , date
     , @prev_id
     , @counter := IF(id = @prev_id, @counter + 1,1) counter
     , @prev_id := id                                prev
FROM table0
   , (SELECT  @prev_id := NULL
            , @counter := 0
     ) init
ORDER BY id, date            
LIMIT 30            
;
```

I add the user defined variable `@prev_id` to see better what happens.

In cases (1) and (2) I get this result:

```
+--------+------------+----------+---------+--------+
|   id   |    date    | @prev_id | counter |  prev  |
+--------+------------+----------+---------+--------+
| 120792 | 2010-03-22 | \N       |       1 | 120792 |
| 120792 | 2010-10-23 | 120792   |       2 | 120792 |
| 120792 | 2010-11-12 | 120792   |       3 | 120792 |
| 120792 | 2011-10-11 | 120792   |       4 | 120792 |
....
| 120792 | 2019-11-20 | 120792   |      18 | 120792 |
| 120792 | 2020-11-18 | 120792   |      19 | 120792 |
| 120792 | 2022-01-24 | 120792   |      20 | 120792 |
+--------+------------+----------+---------+--------+
| 120793 | 2010-03-22 | 120792   |       1 | 120793 |  <- new id which reset counter to 1
| 120793 | 2010-03-26 | 120793   |       2 | 120793 |
| 120793 | 2010-04-07 | 120793   |       3 | 120793 |
....
| 120793 | 2011-09-14 | 120793   |       8 | 120793 |
| 120793 | 2011-10-11 | 120793   |       9 | 120793 |
| 120793 | 2011-12-27 | 120793   |      10 | 120793 |
+--------+------------+----------+---------+--------+
```

This is the result which I expected. But using the combined primary key and additionally index on both columns (case (3)) the output:

```
+--------+------------+----------+---------+--------+
|   id   |    date    | @prev_id | counter |  prev  |
+--------+------------+----------+---------+--------+
| 120792 | 2010-03-22 |   122244 |       1 | 120792 |
| 120792 | 2010-10-23 |   122811 |       1 | 120792 |  <- no addition of 1 since @prev_id is not previous id
| 120792 | 2010-11-12 |   122358 |       1 | 120792 |
| 120792 | 2011-10-11 |   123036 |       1 | 120792 |
....
| 120792 | 2019-11-20 |   654876 |       1 | 120792 |
| 120792 | 2020-11-18 |   910380 |       1 | 120792 |
| 120792 | 2022-01-24 |  1054884 |       1 | 120792 |
+--------+------------+----------+---------+--------+
| 120793 | 2010-03-22 |   120792 |       1 | 120793 |
| 120793 | 2010-03-26 |   122593 |       1 | 120793 |
| 120793 | 2010-04-07 |   122576 |       1 | 120793 |
....
| 120793 | 2011-09-14 |   123080 |       1 | 120793 |
| 120793 | 2011-10-11 |   120792 |       1 | 120793 |
| 120793 | 2011-12-27 |   122038 |       1 | 120793 |
+--------+------------+----------+---------+--------+
```

`@prev_id` in case (3) contains not the previous `id`.

I wanted to show this issue using a simple example with only some few rows but I could not reproduce this: also case (3) had the expected output as in case (1) and (2).

Any idea what happens?

Edit 1:
Here is the `SHOW CREATE TABLE`:

```
CREATE TABLE `table0` (
  `id`         int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `datum`      date NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Primary key and index are added later.

Comment: We need to see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is deprecating the assigning of @variables in `SELECTs`.

MariaDB will probably follow suit at some point.

See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb#index_issue_2_column_pk
for workarounds.

Possible reference (From changelog or reference notes):

---- 2018-10-22 8.0.13 General Availability -- -- Important Change -----

> Setting user variables in statements other than
> [SET](/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-variable.html) is now deprecated due to
> issues that included those listed here:
>
> The order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables was
> undefined.
>
> The default result type of a variable is based on its type at the
> beginning of the statement, which could have unintended effects when a
> variable holding a value of one type at the beginning of a statement
> was assigned a new value of a different type in the same statement.
>
> HAVING, GROUP BY, and ORDER BY clauses, when referring to a variable
> that was assigned a value in the select expression list, did not work
> as expected because the expression was evaluated on the client and so
> it was possible for stale column values from a previous row to be
> used.
>
> Syntax such as SELECT @var, @var:=@var+1 is still accepted in MySQL
> 8.0 for backward compatibility, but is subject to removal in a future release.

Comment: Thanks for the hint of user defined variables but I couldn't find any documentation of depricating user defined variables in `SELECT` statements. Do you have a reference? Also I couldn't find information that innodb does not allow composite primary key. Your link concerns a special case (composite with autoincrement column).